# jQuery: delegate to self?

Tags: jquery, jquery-1.4

First of all, I shall say that I am using an old version of the jQuery library (namely 1.4.2). Updating to jQuery 1.7 will take some time (especially to hunt the bugs), so I am looking for a solution which works in 1.4.2.

I want to write a function :

```
function _setupGui($domNode, selector){
  $domNode
    .delegate(selector, 'mouseenter', function(){ /* do smth awesome */ }
    .delegate(selector, 'mouseleave', function(){ /* do smth awesome */ }
    .delegate(selector, 'click', function(){ /* do smth awesome */ }
}
```

and be able to give a selector which allows to select "self".

Is there a selector, which you can pass to delegate, which allows to select the node holding the delegation ?

In jQuery 1.7, `$domNode.on('click', null, function(){/*handler*/})` does just that, and is the actual implementation of `$domNode.delegate(null, 'click', function(){/*handler*/})`.
However, in 1.4.2, the latter does nothing.

Is this a change in semantics with previous versions ?

Comment: How is that different than just adding a handler to the element instead of delegating?  Maybe I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: @James: you're not, it's just about having a single entry point to bind events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I think you really want is to attach the handlers directly the the element and not use `delegate` at all.  You could just handle this yourself.  Something like this perhaps, where passing "self" means just attach the events:

```
function _setupGui($domNode, selector){
    if(selector == "self"){
        $domNode
          .mouseenter(function(){ /* do smth awesome */ })
          .mouseleave(function(){ /* do smth awesome */ })
          .click(function(){ /* do smth awesome */ })
    }else{
        $domNode
          .delegate(selector, 'mouseenter', function(){ /* do smth awesome */ })
          .delegate(selector, 'mouseleave', function(){ /* do smth awesome */ })
          .delegate(selector, 'click', function(){ /* do smth awesome */ })
    }
}
```

Comment: What I want to do is attach the handlers directly to the element, but using a consistent means that doesn't get stuck in the bind() vs. live() vs. on() vs.... debate.  I think on() was an attempt to do this, but IMHO it amounts to sugar-coating, and you know bugs love sugar.  I have settled on delegate() because it is the underdog in the fight and everyone leaves it alone.  I let everything bubble up to the body or document, because the performance hit is negligible when you consider it mostly happens when a human does something, which isn't that often in the computers time scale.